# How to convert Jenkins UI to Jenkins DSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need Jenkins DSL for purpose of code versioning.
I have seen that there is plugin which allows to convert jobs from groovy code to UI.

Since I have all jobs written in Jenkins UI I am wondering if there is some way to do it the other so that I will get groovy scripts from Jenkins UI jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin [XML Job to Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/XML+Job+to+Job+DSL).
Each Jenkins UI job has config.xml in the file system. I have not used the plugin myself as I have converted Jenkins jobs to script manually.

Comment: I've tried this one it still leaves some sections not converted but it lists those, however it is able to convert large part to DSL, thats really good support.

Comment: Is there any website to get mappings for plugins cause they are often not covered?

Comment: What did you mean with "to get mappings"? Do you need an API reference like https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/? Or are you asking about the configure block https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block? It is used when you did not have ready-to-use API methods.